# how to add multiple autocomplete in django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using built in function to build autocomplete for  many fields:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields

I have following model:

```
 class Ipaddress(models.Model):
        ipaddress=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
        machinename=models.CharField(max_length=500)
        user=models.CharField(max_length=200)
        department= models.ForeignKey('Department',on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='Empty')
        location= models.ForeignKey('Location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        updated = models.DateField("Date Updated",null=True)
        note =models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ipaddress[:50]

class Department(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name[:50] 

class Location(models.Model):
    description= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description[:50]
```

The admin page is here:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pages.models import  Ipaddress, DeviceGroup, Location,Department,
from django_admin_listfilter_dropdown.filters import DropdownFilter, RelatedDropdownFilter

class IpaddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('ipaddress',)}

        search_fields = ['ipaddress']
        autocomplete_fields = ['department',]

        list_display = ('ipaddress', 'machinename', 'user', 'department','location','updated',)
        list_filter = (
        ('user', DropdownFilter),
        ('department', RelatedDropdownFilter),
        ('location', RelatedDropdownFilter),

    )
```

If i change the  `autocomplete_fields = ['location',]` it works but it does not work when i try to change  it department. Also i want to have autocomplete for both department and location at the same time.

The error i am seeing is when  i set `autocomplete_fields = ['department',]`

```
ERRORS:<class 'pages.admin.IpaddressAdmin'>: (admin.E040) ModelAdmin must define    
"search_fields", because it's referenced by 
IpaddressAdmin.autocomplete_fields.
```

Any idea how to fix this error 
I want to some thing like this:

```
 autocomplete_fields = ['department', 'location','user',]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per the documentation that you have referenced in your link [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields)

> You must define search_fields on the related object’s `ModelAdmin` because the autocomplete search uses it.

What this means, in your case and also from the error that you are getting is you need to define your **`search_fields`** on the related object ( in your case **`Department`** and **Location** `ModelAdmin` classes, because the autocomplete search uses it).

So, it would be something like this.

```
class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']

class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['description']
```

Your `autocomplete_fields` on your `IPAddressAdmin` can then be like this.

```
 autocomplete_fields = ['department', 'location',]
```

Comment: Works perfect.  Just need to register
admin.site.register(Department,DepartmentAdmin)
admin.site.register(Location,LocationAdmin)